# Swift - core data capacity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have to design an app that will sustain increasing number of data as time goes by.

For example, let's say I have data model like this.

```
class obj{
  let data1: String
  let data2: String
  init(data1: String, data2: String){
    self.data1 = data1
    self.data2 = data2
  }
}
```

And everyday I have to save new obj.
In such condition, is using core data smart way to keep the data?
Or is it better to prepare database like sql and save data there?
My concern is that app cannot handle so much data after using the app for awhile because the total size of data gets too big at the end...

Sorry I do not have deep knowledge in core data & database.
I appreciate to all of you who share me some knowledge here in advance.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases people use Core Data with a SQLite backing store. It's not like working with SQLite, but it's relevant because you get similar benefits for memory use.

You won't use excessive memory unless you load **lots** of your model objects into memory. For an example like yours that would be an extremely large number of objects. But more typically you use Core Data to load only a subset of the total. Every object where `data1` has a particular string value, for example, or the most recent 20 objects, for example. "Too big" isn't usually a problem. If you **are** loading an enormous number of objects into memory, you'll have problems whether or not you use Core Data.

Comment: I see. You are right that the app won't be utilizing/loading all the data every time. Like you said, most likely 10~20.
But let me confirm if i get you correctly... iOS Calendar app, for example, lets user to save as many events as he/she wants. Although the events may be not viewed at the same time, but all the data are actually save in the phone, meaning it consumes an increase number of memory as we keep using. But what you are saying is I do not have to worry about such memory management unless they are loaded at the same time?

Comment: Be careful to not confuse memory with storage space. Any app uses enough storage space to keep all of its data. But unless it loads all that data at once, it doesn't use that much memory.

Comment: ohh okay. Yeah i was definitely confused. Thank you!